# PostgreSQL query returns ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json

Tags: postgresql

I have PostgreSQL query where I need to return vehicleId, plateNumber and one last "position" data in order to see where the vehicle stopped. I have three tables. Vehicle table, session table storing the sessions and tracking table storing the actual position data of the vehicle.

Getting the plateNumber and vehicleId does work, however adding the position and trying to group the results will end with the following error: ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type JSON.

Is there any way around this. How could I force (convert the JSON) so it can be actually measured? The JSON contains position data from the mobile which seem to be having a unified structure. There is timestamp, lat, long, speed and heading.

Alternatively is there any other way the query could be written as not to involve the need to compare the JSON data? Any recommendation? I have tried a few different approaches with no result. I always seem to hit the issue with the JSON.

```
SELECT "plateNumber", "Config.Vehicle"."vehicleId", position
FROM "Config.Vehicle"
INNER JOIN "Config.Session" ON "Config.Session"."vehicleId" = "Config.Vehicle"."vehicleId"
LEFT JOIN (select * from "Config.Tracking" ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) a ON a."sessionId" = "Config.Session"."sessionId"
WHERE "Config.Session"."sessionEnd" IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Use JSONB instead of JSON (which column is the JSON column btw?)

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names